# flask service cannot communicate with postgres via docker-compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose

getting an error which says it cannot make connections with my postgres database

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "clean_life_database_1" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 4444?
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        build: .
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_URI=postgresql://postgresuser123:mysecret@clean_life_database_1:4444
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        networks:
            - db_new

    database:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgresuser123
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecret
        ports:
            - 4444:5432
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - db_new

networks:
    db_new:
        driver: bridge
```

also, the folder in which the project resides is clean_life, so when i checked the container names, it gives me clean_life_database_1

why does it prefex with my folder name and the suffix it with a 1?

Comment: Compose uses that convention to generate container names (to distinguish from other running Compose projects; to support scaling above 1 replica), but you can use the service names as host names.  Connections between containers ignore `ports:`; you should be able to use `database:5432` using the standard PostgreSQL port.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) on networking in compose, it looks like you should instead set your database host to `database` (as it's the name of your database container).

You're also setting up a network `db_new` which could also be used for the `web` and `database` services to talk to each other but I'll leave that up to you.

So as an updated compose file you should have:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        build: .
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_URI=postgresql://postgresuser123:mysecret@database:4444
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        networks:
            - db_new

    database:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgresuser123
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecret
        ports:
            - 4444:5432
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - db_new

networks:
    db_new:
        driver: bridge
```